# Add a machine in an active directory domain in Windows 2008 - DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I'm trying to add one of my machine to an Active Directory domain.
1) I added a record for my domain controller to the host file of the machine to translate its IP address 
2) In the "Member of" field in the settings, I wrote the domain I wanna join. 
3) I click on OK

I get this error :

```
The error was: "No records found for given DNS query.
(error code 0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.***
```

It seems that the domain name is still unaccessible, as if the host file didn't make a difference. The weird thing is that I can access the domain name from a browser on the machine. So I really don't know where the error comes from.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `The weird thing is that I can access the domain name from a browser on the machine` - What does that mean exactly? Also, why are you using the hosts files and not configuring the DNS client settings to use the DC for DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active directory doesn’t function without DNS services supporting it.

Using a HOSTS file is not going to work unless you add every single resource record necessary to support your domain.

Because you have a DNS server configured if you have an Active Directory Domain, you should use it.

Comment: Right ! Indeed, a DNS server was automatically set up when I set the AD. So I have to point my machine to this DNS which will contain the right record referring to the AD, is that right ?

Comment: Yes. All AD joined computers use the AD domain controller as their DNS server. The AD DNS server has forwarders setup to your external ISP DNS servers. The IP configuration is usually handed out by DHCP which should be configured to hand out the proper DNS address.